# android tutorial teleop: missing ids in R.java of honeycomb

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

In the MainActivity of android_tutorial_teleop there are some things wrong I think:

In MainActivity.java these are used:

- R.id.virtual_joystick_snap
- R.id.virtual_joystick
- R.id.visualization

And in res/menu/settings_menu.xml

- @+id/virtual_joystick_properties
- @+id/virtual_joystick_snap

And in res/layout/main.xml

- @+id/virtual_joystick

The compiler looks for these ids in the R.java of android_honeycomb_mr2 but the only (relevant) id that is in there is *public static int virtual_joystick_layout=0x7f05003b;*.

How can I solve this. I could really use this tutorial.

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33365/android-tutorial-teleop:-missing-ids-in-r.java-of-honeycomb/) by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I rebuild android_core and the problem is solved.

---

Originally posted by [Kat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1982/kat/) with karma: 155 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0